# Proof verification: Mittag-Leffler Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Mittag-Leffler theorem can be stated as follows.

> Given a sequence of polynomials $P_n(z)= \sum_{k=1}^{d_n}c_{n, k} x^k$, prove that there exists a meromorphic function $f$ whose only poles are at $\{ a_n \}_{n \ge 1}$ with principal part $P_n \left (\frac{1}{z-a_n}\right )$.

I tried to prove it myself and succeed to get a proof which looks right for me. Here is the proof which I want to get verified.

> For integer $k \ge 1$, define canonical factor by
> \begin{eqnarray} 
> E_k (z) = (1-z) e^{z+ \frac{z^2}{2} + \cdots + \frac{z^k}{k}}.
>  \end{eqnarray}
> Note that $E_k (z)$ is entire. Now, Define $f$ by
> \begin{align}
> f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{d_n} c_{n, k} \frac{1- \left ( E_{N_{n, k}}(\frac{z}{a_n} )\right )^k}{(z-a_n)^k}
> \end{align}
> Here, $N_{n, k}$ are sufficiently large natural numbers, which will be defined later. 
>
> First, we show that $f$ defined above is holomorphic except at $\{a_n\}$. It is sufficient to prove that $f$ is holomorphic in $S=\{ z : |z| \le R, z \neq a_i \}$ where $R$ is any real.
> \begin{align}
> f(z) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{d_n} c_{n, k} \frac{1- \left ( E_{N_{n, k}}(\frac{z}{a_n} )\right )^k}{(z-a_n)^k} \\
> &= \sum_{|a_n| \le 2R} \sum_{k=1}^{d_n} c_{n, k} \frac{1- \left ( E_{N_{n, k}}(\frac{z}{a_n} )\right )^k}{(z-a_n)^k} + \sum_{|a_n| > 2R} \sum_{k=1}^{d_n} c_{n, k} \frac{1- \left ( E_{N_{n, k}}(\frac{z}{a_n} )\right )^k}{(z-a_n)^k}
> \end{align}
> Since first term is obviously holomorphic in $S$, we shall prove second term is holomorphic by proving that it converges uniformly on $S$. Now observe that if $|a_n|>2|z|$,
> \begin{align}
> \left | 1 - \left ( E_N \left (\frac{z}{a_n}\right) \right )^k \right | &= \left | \exp(0) - \exp\left({-k \sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{\left ( \frac{z}{a_n}\right )^j}{j}}\right )\right | \\
> &\le Ck\sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{\left|\frac{z}{a_n}\right|^j}{j} \\
> &\le \frac{Ck}{N \cdot 2^N}.
> \end{align}
> (To make first inequality holds for appropriate constant $C$, $\frac{k}{N \cdot 2^N}$ needs to be bounded, which can be obtained by choosing $N$ (actually $N_{n, k}$) bigger than $d_n$.) Thus,
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{|a_n| > 2R}\sum_{k=1}^{d_n}\left | c_{n, k}  \frac{1- \left ( E_{N_{n, k}}(\frac{z}{a_n} )\right )^k}{(z-a_n)^k} \right | \le \sum_{|a_n| > 2R}\sum_{k=1}^{d_n}\frac{C  k |c_{n, k}|}{N_{n, k} 2^{N_{n, k}} R^k}
> \end{align}
> We can choose sufficiently large $N_{n, k}$ such that above sum converges absolutely. (To give more detail, we can choose $N_{n, k}$ such that sequence $\frac{k|c_{n, k}|}{N 2^N}$ decreases rapidly, for example in $2^{-m}$ scale.) Thus, holomorphicity is proved. 
>
> Second, we prove that $f$ has pole at $a_n$, with principal part $P_n \left ( \frac{1}{z-a_n} \right )$. To show this, we only need to prove that
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{k=1}^{d_n} c_{n, k} \frac{1-\left ( E_{N_{n, k}} \left( \frac{z}{a_n}\right)\right)^k}{(z-a_n )^k} - P_n \left ( \frac{1}{z-a_n} \right )
> \end{align}
> is holomorphic near $a_n$. (Holomorphicity at other points far away from $a_n$, and holomorphicity of remaining part of $f(z)$ near $a_n$ can be similarly proved by argument at first part of the proof.)
> \begin{align}
> &\sum_{k=1}^{d_n} c_{n, k} \frac{1-\left ( E_{N_{n, k}} \left( \frac{z}{a_n}\right)\right)^k}{(z-a_n )^k} - P_n \left ( \frac{1}{z-a_n} \right )  \\
> &= -\sum_{k=1}^{d_n} c_{n, k} \frac{\left ( E_{N_{n, k}} \left( \frac{z}{a_n}\right)\right)^k}{(z-a_n )^k} \\
> &= -\sum_{k=1}^{d_n} c_{n, k} \left (\frac{\exp\left ( \frac{z}{a_n} + \frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{z}{a_n} \right )^2 + \cdots + \frac{1}{N_{n, k}} \left ( \frac{z}{a_n} \right )^{N_{n, k}}\right )}{-a_n} \right )^k
> \end{align}
> is holomorphic near $a_n$, and the proof is completed.

Thank you for reading my bad-written proof. 
If you find any error, no matter small or big, please let me know.
Any other advices are also welcome.